# Anagrams, Prime numbers and Prime number coding

Tags: prime-numbers, maximal-and-prime-ideals

A while back I realised that I could find all anagrams in a language by assigning each letter to a prime number (I call this prime coding, though it probably has a proper name) then multiply the letters in a word to create some value. Then words that are anagrams will have the same value.

When I thought about this practically, the numbers started getting pretty big. A 10 letter word is likely to be over 1 trillion. In an attempt to reduce these values I turned to Gaussian Integers. So that I could use smaller numbers as my primes.

- Are there any more types of prime numbers I could use to further reduce values?

I suspect Quarternions and Octonians(?) and further powers of 2 down that route could potentially reduce the value at a cost of the number of numbers needed. So presumably there would be an optimal pay off here. But I'm more interested in a different approach.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think what you are looking for is known in computer science as a hash function for a multiset. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3390/is-there-a-hash-function-for-a-collection-i-e-multi-set-of-integers-that-has